# What is the Nvidia drivers [number] command doing?

Tags: drivers

I want to understand why and what the below command does. People seem to just pluck the nvidia-[number] out of thin air, and I can't find any reference or documentation on where they seem to have magically got the number from. Could someone spare the time to explain what the number is, and how to find/use the command that I need to use for a graphics card in the future?

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-331
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Nvidia-331` is the name of a package, containing Nvidia drivers version 331.xx.

You can see which Nvidia driver versions exist at [Nvidia site](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us).

You can also see which versions are at xorg-edgers [HERE](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa).

If you start Ubuntu Synaptic application and search for "nvidia", you will see which Nvidia drivers are present in official repositories and what are package names.

Comment: Oh! Now I see where it is. I actually used the Nvidia website to install my card, which is a GTX 970. So would I install the :
sudo-apt get install nvidia-353.06 one?

Comment: 353.06 is a beta I guess. The recommended stable one is 352.21. You can install it from xorg-edgers by `sudo apt-get install nvidia-352`

Comment: See, how do you know how to figure it out? Where do I find the recommended stable one?

Comment: There are two kinds of recomendations ;-). One from Ubuntu. You can find it at System Settings -> Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers. That is not always up to date for new adapters. The other is at Nvidia site.

Comment: On in my case, it's not in the additional drivers list, so I had to use the Nvidia website. I just can't see on the website where it says that version 352 is the most stable so I was hoping you could tell me how you found that out?

Comment: http://www.geforce.com/drivers

Comment: I just tested this and now I see the drivers in the additional drivers list again. I can't thank you enough!